# Print object only when conditions met

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I have three objects and two associations. My objects are `Owner`, `Jockey`, and `Horse`, and the associations are `OwnerID` (`Owner`) -> `OwnerID` (`Jockey`) and `JockeyID` (`Jockey`) -> `JockeyID` (`Horse`).

On the page for my `Owner`, I would like to print all `Horse`s. I did this like so:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>JockeyID</th>
</tr>
  
  <% @subject.FirstAssociation.SecondAssociation.each do |horse| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <%= horse['Name'].first %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= horse['JockeyID'].first %>
  </td>
  </tr>
   <% end %>

</table>
```

This is close to what I want: it prints out all of the horses owned an Owner, but I would like to display, following these associations (so for this `Owner`) all of the `Horse`s which have a `JockeyID = 7`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand how the view code is even functional. Please update your question with the code for the relevant models and associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<% @subject.FirstAssociation.find(7/jokeyid).SecondAssociation.each do |horse| %>
```

Comment: Throws an error, are you sure this is correct? Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: if you can post <% @subject.FirstAssociation.find(7/jokeyid).SecondAssociation.each do |horse| %> with actual association then I can easily give you actual changes required